# Extra spacing in Vim when copying and pasting from Chrome

Tags: vim

Whenever I copy text that has been indented into Vim from Chrome, I get a cascading indent instead of a consistent one, so:

```
def fn(x):
    """Takes x as an input and returns y
    if x:
        return y
```

becomes:

```
def fn(x):                                                                  
        """Takes x as an input and returns y                                
                if x:                                                       
                                return y
```

How do I prevent this (preferred), or how do I quickly fix the spacing using other vim commands (acceptable)?

#### Extra Info

- vim 7.4, chromium 34 on Arch Linux
- Copy method: highlight (mouse or otherwise) in Chromium, `CTRL-C`, switch to vim and insert mode, `SHIFT-CTRL-V`.

Comment: Ignore the fact that it says Mac OS X. The solution is the same.

Comment: The song remains the same.

Comment: @FDinoff Thank you I never would have found that in the search.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you paste using any of your terminal/OS's default method (menu, contextual menu, shortcut, mouse…) the text is not pasted: it is *inserted* as if you typed it. Because you have enabled autoindenting, Vim indents every line and you end up with that stairway (to hell) effect.

You have two options…

1. `paste/nopaste` and/or `pastetoggle`:

   You can do `:set paste` to disable autoindenting and formatting before you paste and do `:set nopaste` afterward.

   If you decide to take that path, I suggest you read `:h pastetoggle` to make the whole process a little less taxing.
2. Vim's own commands and clipboard integration:

   If your Vim build comes with clipboard support, you can use `"+p` or `"*p` to paste from other programs without side effects.

   The default Vim that comes with most OSes is a "small" build that may lack a number of useful features. If you intend to use Vim as your primary editor for programming it is advised to install a beefier build that comes with clipboard support. On Debian-based systems, the best choice is usually "vim-gtk" or "vim-gnome". On Arch, I think you have to install the "gvim" package.

Comment: Cool! I actually already have the `gvim` package, so `"+p` works. Really awkward key combo though. I will look into `pastetoggle` as well. Had no idea about `paste` mode.